# Redefining infolines in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm realizing my first presentation in beamer.
I'm using the CambridgeUS theme, and I want to redefine the infolines so I can show

- the title of the presentation on the headline
- author, institute, date and counter on the footline

I wrote the following code

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{2ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

but i got the following error

> File ended while scanning use of \beamer@sbtexec

I think the error is in the definition of headline.
In fact, if I wrote the following code

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{2ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

all work well, but I had to define two useless beamercolorbox.
Where is the error?

Also, I would like to hide the headlines in the first frame of the presentation.

How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a final closing brace in the `headline` definition:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{2ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}% <- this closing brace was missing
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author{The Author}
\title{The Title}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I took the liberty to slightly increase the height for the box in the headline (this is just a suggestion, of course, and you can revert to your original settings).

To suppress the `headline` *and* `footline`, use the `plain` option for `frame`; to suppress one template only, redefine it locally to be empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{2ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author{The Author}
\title{The Title}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
test
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And what can I do about my other two questions?

Comment: @Andrea Sorry; I overlooked the other question. Please see my updated answer. Regarding the question about the logo, this was not in the original question, and you don't provide any code showing logos. Please edit your question and add there a simple document showing the problem with the logo. In future occasions, however, do not add questions to your posts after the original ones have been addressed (this is not a forum) and open new questions instead.

Comment: You're right, I opened a new question, thank you.